# What are independent events.

Tags: probability

If in a question it is given that find probability of getting two Ace if two cards are drawn (without replacement) from the pack of 52 cards.

While solving such question we say that event E=first card is Ace and F=second card is Ace are two independent events, but P(E)= 4/52 and P(F)=3/51. As we can see that if we draw the first card then one Ace will become less and total number of card also decrease by one ,while drawing the second card. So how can we say that E and F are independent events.

(Feel free to edit if any.)

Comment: $E$ and $F$ are NOT independent events because $P(E|F)\neq P(F)$.

Comment: Thanks everyone to clear my doubt 

Answer (score 2):

The events $E$ and $F$ are not independent. The values of $\mathbb P(E), \mathbb P(F)$ themselves don't necessarily have to do with that, but looking at your numbers you seem to be getting at the correct proof: $\mathbb P(F \mid E) = \frac{3}{51} \neq \frac{4}{52} = \mathbb P(F)$, so $E$ and $F$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

You're not thinking about 'independence' correctly here. I may be wrong, but I think you are thinking:

"Well, the second card is not the same as the first card. Indeed, the drawing of a first card is 'separate' from the drawing of the second card.   So, with the first card being an ace, the second card can still be an ace as well. These are two 'different' events, and thus independent."

However, this is not what independent means.

Two events are independent if and only if the occurrence of the one event does not effect the probability of the second. So, while the first card being an ace does indeed not rule out the second card being an ace, it *does* effect its probability:  when the first card is an ace, the probability of the second card being an ace as well is of course lower than if the first card is not an ace.  So, these two events are in fact *not* independent.

Answer (score 1):

There IS a sense in which the drawing of the cards are independent events.

Let $P_n$ be the probability that the $n^{th}$ card is drawn, then it is a premise of your question that $P_1=1$ and $P_2=1$

What is NOT independent, is the probability that the 2nd card is an ace, dependent upon the result of the first card drawn.  It's important to be precise about what is independent of what.